# POST using XMLHttpRequest with existing source

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

What I am trying to do only using XMLHttpRequest, is this:

- The script downloads a web page, that has only one form in it.
- The script inserts text into a field.
- The script submits the form, while keeping all details about input tags.

I did the first part, but I have no idea how to finish with the next two steps.

Note: I do not have control over the page downloaded, and it is not well-formed XML/HTML.

Could someone explain to me how I can get this done?

This is for a Google Chrome extension, so I have all permissions needed.

EDIT: this is my current code:

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://www.mysite.com/my/testpage.aspx",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
        html: http0.responseText.between("<body>", "</body>")
              },
        success: function(data) {
            var dom = $(data),
            form = dom.filter('form');
            form.attr('onsubmit', 'document.getElementById("error").value = "I\'m done!"; document.getElementById("helpmebutton").disabled = false;');
            form.attr('action', 'http://www.mysite.com/my/testpage.aspx');
            $('#tempdiv').append(form);
            form.find('input[name="ctl00$ctl00$cphSite$cphMySiteContent$linkLocation"]').val(document.getElementById("result").value);
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really use jQuery to save yourself time and headaches.

Create a temporary `div` with id `tempdiv` and put everything in that `div`. Then, fill in appropriate elements and submit the form, like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://...",
         success: function(data) {
             var dom = $(data),
                 form = dom.filter('form');

             $('#tempdiv').append(form);

             form.find('input:text').val(123);
             // all input[type=text] get value 123

             form.submit();
         }
});
```

Comment: This did not work. I will edit the question with more details.

Comment: @Bogdacutu: Perhaps I misunderstand. This is a demo of what I mean (I did correct some things): http://jsfiddle.net/UELKF/.

Comment: I'm going to try it; but how can I change `form.find('input:text').val(123);` to select the input by name?

Comment: @Bogdactu: Those are basically CSS selectors, so e.g. `input[name="something"]`.

Comment: I'm going to try, and come back to post the results. Upvoting anyway :)

Comment: I got it working, but it gives me an error on `form.submit()`:`Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_OnSubmit is not defined`. I just found out that the form has javascript in onSubmit: `<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="/my/test.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">`. How can I replace that with my own script?

Comment: @Bogdacutu: You're trying to do tricky things, but you can replace the attribute with `form.attr('onsubmit', '')`. The second string is the new value, so this clears the attribute.

Comment: Ok, I almost got it working, but I had to replace `action` with an absolute URL, and now it just goes through the script without actually submitting the form. I think this happened because it should be relative to the script, right?

Comment: @Bogdacutu: I guess so, your scenario sounds a bit weird, but if it works that's great :)

Comment: It doesn't submit the form at all. Should I give you the code I currently have?

Comment: @Bogdacutu: What error does it give now you've removed those attributes? Perhaps some code is useful.

Comment: Edited question; it does not give me any message in the Chrome error log. And the code in `onsubmit` gets executed. Actually, was the page supposed to redirect?

Comment: @Bogdacutu: The form must contain an `action` attribute, so it should redirect. Is no navigating happening and no errors either?

Comment: No, the page was redirecting to `/my/testpage.aspx` before making the `action` URL absolute, and the page didn't exist, so I got an error page. Now, I don't have any errors or navigation.

Comment: Actually, I checked the network logs, it's getting submited. Thanks!